# Using Namespaces and Databases together

Tags: php, mysql, namespaces

The way I used to use a database would be

```
class sitedb
{
    public $db = '';
    public $config;
    public $settings = array(
        'host'      => "localhost",
        'database'  => "database",
        'username'  => "user",
        'password'  => "pass",
    );

    public function __construct(){

        $this->db = new PDO(
            "mysql:host={$this->settings['host']};" .
            "dbname={$this->settings['database']};" .
            "charset=utf8",
            "{$this->settings['username']}",
            "{$this->settings['password']}"
        );

        $this->db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    }
}
```

And then say I have a user script that uses this database

```
class User {
      public function __construct() {
             $this->db = new sitedb();
      }
}
```

Now within my code I could use `$resource = $this->db->db->prepare($query);`

A friend of mine recently suggested I used namespaces instead and it would make things easier than the constructor every time, but not sure how to go about this.

I have my database class file

```
namespace database;


class site
{
    public $db = '';
    public $config;
    public $settings = array(
        'host'      => "localhost",
        'database'  => "database",
        'username'  => "user",
        'password'  => "pass",
    );

    public function __construct(){

        $this->db = new PDO(
            "mysql:host={$this->settings['host']};" .
            "dbname={$this->settings['database']};" .
            "charset=utf8",
            "{$this->settings['username']}",
            "{$this->settings['password']}"
        );

        $this->db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    }

}

class auth
{

}
```

My thought process here was that I could use

```
$resource = \database\site::????
```

Now I'm at a loss as to how to actually connect. I'm hoping I drew up my issue well enough to show what I'm after. I'm just not sure how I can use this to actually connect to the database.

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding what namespaces are. Using namespaces doesn't change how you instantiate classes (except from the need to add the namespace).  [Read more about namespaces here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.php). How ever, I would suggest looking into the Factory pattern for your DB-class. The way you're using it now, you will create a new DB-instance (and connection) in every place you're using it. You should pass the same instance around instead.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what you mean by the factory pattern @MagnusEriksson, but I will look into it. I'm assuming I'm missing a close. (I've been notorious for that since mysql_connect). As far as the namespace goes I'm thinking you're saying with my user class I would still need to construct the same way I used to.

Comment: I think you should read up in Namespaces first. Then read up on the Factory pattern... But yes, you can. more or less, build your classes in the same way. If I were you, I would probably not build my own DB-class, but rather use some existing library. No need to reinvent the wheel. :)

Comment: Will definitely read on it. Started converting some of my non database related classes to namespaces and classes and I love the logic behind it, but gotta be careful with the db information. =D Appreciate the help @MagnusEriksson